# How do you use a variable as a field on a Webfocus report?

Tags: webfocus

I have a report in which I have the current date stored in a variable, and I want to include it as field on the report. I tried this:

```
-SET &WORKDATE = AYMD(&YYMD,0,'I8YYMD') ;
-SET &SAVEDATE=EDIT(&WORKDATE,'99999999$');
.....
.....
BY
    '&SAVEDATE'  AS 'Date Rpt Run'
```

I also tried:

```
BY
    &SAVEDATE  AS 'Date Rpt Run'
```

Both give me

```
(FOC003) THE FIELDNAME IS NOT RECOGNIZED: 20140430
BYPASSING TO END OF COMMAND
```

What is the proper syntax for including a variable in the report?  Output of the report is Excel, if that matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about you try

```
-SET &BYTODAY = &YYMD;

DEFINE FILE TABLE1
BYDATE/I8YYMD = &BYTODAY;
END
TABLE FILE TABLE1
...
BY BYDATE
...
```

Comment: I ended up doing something like that. It seems contrived to me though that you have to include a basically global variable in the DEFINE TABLE section and define it again. Oh well.

Comment: The reason is because the query wouldn't understand the string 20140521 as the name of a group by field, that's why we define a field and add the value to all the rows

Comment: I know, I just think its a bad language design.

Comment: It's not really bad language design, it's necessary. You have to have a named field in order to group by it. Get out of WebFOCUS for a sec and think of it like a SQL query:

`SELECT product_id, price
FROM tblProducts
GROUP BY 12`

It just would make no sense; the query language doesn't know what that means. You have to tell it to group by a field that you're selecting.